# Subscribe to this Blog for a Private P2 Themed Site?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, email, subscription, theme-p2

What's the easiest way to get a **subscribe to this blog** for a private [P2-Themed](http://p2theme.com) Site?  I want to have an obvious link on the page without having to modify the theme so that everyone using the site can easily see the link.

Ideally I'd also be able to see who is subscribed and if possible subscribe them myself *(it's the team members for the project I want to make sure are subscribed.)*

Suggestion for the best plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a combination of Subscribe to Comments and Subscribe2, but it's not pretty.

Comment: So no good solution?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's just a matter of someone taking the time to write the plugin for this, though.